# How to disable touchscreen, but not the pen?

Tags: samsung, touchscreen

I have a Samsung ATIV 700T. I had installed Linux Ubuntu in it, and I want to do digital art with it, I found a way to install Paint Tool SAI which helps me to draw, but I want to disable touchscreen while using pen to draw. I was using an artdock when it was Windows, but now I can't install that artdock since it isn't compatible with Linux. Do you have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn on/off pointer devices, like touch screen, i made a script. Step by step instruction:

In console:

```
$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M705                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06FD:01 04F3:300F UNKNOWN              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ xinput disable 12
$ xinput disable 13
```

I found my devices with ID 12 and 13. It's time to make script that turns them on/off. Create a file `/usr/bin/touch-toggle`

```
#!/bin/sh
# This shell script is PUBLIC DOMAIN. You may do whatever you want with it.

TOGGLE=$HOME/.touch-toggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    xinput disable 12
    xinput disable 13
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/status/touchpad-disabled.png "Touch toggle" "Disabled Touchpad and Touchscreen"
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    xinput enable 12
    xinput enable 13
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/24x24/devices/input-touchpad.png "Touch toggle" "Enabled Touchpad and Touchscreen"
fi
```

Don't forget to change device IDs to yours. Add execute permission and run script in console

```
chmod a+x /usr/bin/touch-toggle
touch-toggle
touch-toggle
```

Works okay? Create shortcut on desktop or add to hotkey.

More info and pictures on https://blackcrystal.net/en/uncategorized/turn-on-off-touch-devices-in-ubuntu-14-04/ it works fine in 14.04 and 16.04

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers: include the essential parts of the article instead, and reference the article with a link at the bottom or top.

Comment: When I write xinput, it doesn't show the touch screen. And there isn't touch-toggle file in my /usr/bin

Comment: Maybe your screen have different name, without "Touch" in name?
`touch-toggle` is name of the script you can create in /usr/bin , you can give it any name.